# Total price does not change, I expect to see change in Total price while changing the numbers?

Tags: javascript, list, price, calculation

I am writing a price list for visualization. In this price list user can choose his project function, style and the rendering style (Photo realistic/Conceptual/Maket) and at the same time see the total price of the project at the bottom of the list. I can't figure out why the code doesn't calculate the price...

```
  <html>
  <div id="RenderingTab" class="panel panel-default" >
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-
 parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseTwo1">Render</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <form>
        <div class="panel-body">Project style :<br>
          <br>
          <div class="col-lg-6" data-toggle="buttons">
            <select id="prjstrndr" class="panel-title" 
 onchange="RndrPrcCalc(this);">
              <option  class="input-group-addon" value="1.3" id="rndr-mdrn" 
 onchange="RndrPrcCalc(this); RndrIntPrc(this);" name="options" >
              Modern </option>

              <option  class="input-group-addon" value="1" id="rndr-cls" 
 onchange="RndrPrcCalc(this); RndrIntPrc(this);" name="options"  >
              Classic </option>

              <option  class="input-group-addon" value="1.8" id="rndr-trd" 
 onchange="RndrPrcCalc(this); RndrIntPrc(this);" name="options"  >
              Traditional </option>

              <option  class="input-group-addon" value="0.9" id="rndr-param" 
onchange="RndrPrcCalc(this); RndrIntPrc(this);" name="options"  >
              Parametric </option>

              <option  class="input-group-addon" value="1.1" id="rndr-org" 
onchange="RndrPrcCalc(this); RndrIntPrc(this);" name="options"  >
              Organic </option>
              </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <form>
        <div class="panel-body">Project Function :<br>
          <br>
          <div class="col-lg-6" data-toggle="buttons">
             <select id="prjfnrndr" class="panel-title" 
onchange="RndrPrcCalc(this);">

              <option  class="input-group-addon" value="1.2" id="rndr-vll" 
onchange="RndrPrcCalc(this); RndrIntPrc(this);" name="style">
              Villa </option>

              <option  class="input-group-addon" value="1" id="rndr-
apprtmnt" onchange="RndrPrcCalc(this); RndrIntPrc(this);" name="style" >
              Appartment </option>

              <option  class="input-group-addon" value="1.35" id="rndr-
cmmrcl" onchange="RndrPrcCalc(this); RndrIntPrc(this);" name="style" >
              Commercial </option>

              <option  class="input-group-addon" value="1.3" id="rndr-offcl" 
onchange="RndrPrcCalc(this); RndrIntPrc(this);" name="style" >
              Official </option>

              <option  class="input-group-addon" value="1.25" id="rndr-othr" 
onchange="RndrPrcCalc(this); RndrIntPrc(this);" name="style" >
              Other </option>
              </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

        <br>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-
 parent="#accordion3" href="#collapseTwo3"> Interior Rendering</a></h4>
              </div>
 <div id="collapseTwo3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">

                  <br>
                  <div id="rndr-lobbyParam" >
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm"><span 
class="input-group-addon paramtitle">Lobby wall area  </span>
                      <input type="number" min="0" step="0.01" id="rndr-int-
 wall-area-lobby" class="form-control" onchange="RndrIntPrc();" 
 placeholder=" 0.00     sqm " required="required">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm"><span 
 class="input-group-addon paramtitle">Photo Realistic </span>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                          <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-
  addon">Day</span>
                            <input type="number" min="0" id="rndr-int-real-
   day-lobby" class="form-control" placeholder="0 Num" 
 onchange="RndrIntPrc();">
                          </div>
                          <!-- /input-group --> 
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                          <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-
  addon"> Night</span>
                            <input type="number" min="0" id="rndr-int-real-
nght-lobby" class="form-control" placeholder="0 Num" 
 onchange="RndrIntPrc();">
                          </div>
                          <!-- /input-group --> 
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col-lg-6 --> 
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm"><span 
   class="input-group-addon paramtitle">Conceptual</span>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                          <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-
 addon">Day</span>
                            <input type="number" min="0" id="rndr-int-conc-
   day-lobby" class="form-control" placeholder="0 Num" 
  onchange="RndrIntPrc();">
                          </div>
                          <!-- /input-group --> 
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                          <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-
    addon"> Night</span>
                            <input type="number" min="0" id="rndr-int-conc-
 nght-lobby" class="form-control" placeholder="0 Num" 
   onchange="RndrIntPrc();">
                          </div>
                          <!-- /input-group --> 
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col-lg-6 --> 
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm"><span 
    class="input-group-addon paramtitle">Maket</span>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                          <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-
    addon">Day</span>
                            <input type="number" min="0" id="rndr-int-mak-
   day-lobby" class="form-control" placeholder="0 Num" onchange="RndrIntPrc();">
                          </div>
                          <!-- /input-group --> 
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                          <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-
    addon" disabled="disabled"> Night</span>
                            <input type="number" min="0" id="rndr-int-mak-
   nght-lobby" class="form-control" placeholder="0 Num" disabled="disabled">
                          </div>

  <br>

 <label class="fa">Interior rendering Total price  </label>
    <input type="text"  class="form-control"  id="render-int-price" 
    placeholder= "0" readonly></input>
   </html>

      <script>
     document.getElementById("prjstrndr").onchange = function() 
       {RndrIntPrc();};
    document.getElementById("prjfnrndr").onchange = function()
    {RndrIntPrc();};
    document.getElementById("rndr-lobby").onchange = function() 
    {RndrIntPrc();};


     document.getElementById("rndr-int-wall-area-lobby").onchange = 
   function() {RndrIntPrc();};
    document.getElementById("rndr-int-real-day-lobby").onchange = function() 
  {RndrIntPrc();};
    document.getElementById("rndr-int-real-nght-lobby").onchange = 
   function() {RndrIntPrc();};
    document.getElementById("rndr-int-conc-day-lobby").onchange = function() 
 {RndrIntPrc();};
    document.getElementById("rndr-int-conc-nght-lobby").onchange = 
   function() 
               {RndrIntPrc();};
    document.getElementById("rndr-int-mak-day-lobby").onchange = function() 
    {RndrIntPrc();};

   //interior render cost calculation:

   var       
          RIRDL = document.getElementById("rndr-int-real-day-lobby"),
          RIRNL = document.getElementById("rndr-int-real-nght-lobby"),
          RICDL = document.getElementById("rndr-int-conc-day-lobby"),
          RICNL = document.getElementById("rndr-int-conc-nght-lobby"),
          RIMDL = document.getElementById("rndr-int-mak-day-lobby"),







          Totalintrndr = 0;

          document.getElementById('render-int-price').value = Totalintrndr;

    var RndrIntPrc = function() {

    var       projectStylerndr = document.getElementById('prjstrndr').value,
          projectFunctionrndr = document.getElementById('prjfnrndr').value,

          RIWAL = document.getElementById("rndr-int-wall-area-lobby").value,
          RIRDLNum = RIRDL.value,
          RIRNLNum = RIRNL.value,
          RICDLNum = RICDL.value,
          RICNLNum = RICNL.value,
          RIMDLNum = RIMDL.value,

          XRL = 50000,
          XCL = 25000,
          XML = 10000,


    var intNumD = [];

   [RIRDLNum,RICDLNum,RIMDLNum].forEach(function(n, i) {
   intNumD[i] = (n >= 2 && n < 5) ? n * 0.9 : n == 0 ? 0 : n == 1 ? 1 : n - 1;
});

 var intNumN = [];

 [RIRNLNum,RICNLNum].forEach(function(n, i) {
   intNumN[i] = (n >= 2 && n < 5) ? n * 0.95 : n == 0 ? 0 : n == 1 ? 1.2 : n == 2 ? 1.9 : n - 1;
});





        var     Totalintrndr = projectStylerndr * projectFunctionrndr * 
       (Math.log(RIWAL)*((XRL)*(intNumD[0] + intNumN[0]) + (XCL)*(intNumD[1] 
       + intNumN[1]) + (XML)*intNumD[2]) );




             document.getElementById('render-int-price').value = 
             (Totalintrndr>0 && Totalintrndr!=='NaN')?Totalintrndr:0;

     };


    </script>
```

Comment: There are a bunch of javascript errors in this code which are pretty obvious, a var line following a line ending with a comma, "rndr-lobby" doesn't exist, so, if your problem is just fixing those bugs use your browser console to find and fix them.  If your problem is unrelated to that, fix your code here first so we can test it.

Comment: the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing all typo bugs you have to read some JS manuals, than take some Math course. 
Now seriously:

1. Math.log(x) - returns number < 0 if x < 1. So unless rndr-int-wall-area-lobby < 1 - you will get "0" as total price.
2. option element doesn't have onchange

From JavaScript perspective it will work.

See working version of your code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/49a8oddd/)

```
<html>
<div id="RenderingTab" class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data- parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseTwo1">Render</a></h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseTwo1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <form>
      <div class="panel-body">Project style :<br>
        <br>
        <div class="col-lg-6" data-toggle="buttons">
          <select id="prjstrndr" class="panel-title" onchange="RndrIntPrc(this);">
              <option  class="input-group-addon" value="1.3"  > Modern </option>
              <option  class="input-group-addon" value="1"   > Classic </option>
              <option  class="input-group-addon" value="1.8"  > Traditional </option>
              <option  class="input-group-addon" value="0.9"   > Parametric </option>
              <option  class="input-group-addon" value="1.1"   > Organic </option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <form>
      <div class="panel-body">Project Function :<br>
        <br>
        <div class="col-lg-6" data-toggle="buttons">
          <select id="prjfnrndr" class="panel-title" onchange="RndrPrcCalc(this);">
              <option  class="input-group-addon" value="1.2" >Villa </option>
              <option  class="input-group-addon" value="1" >Appartment </option>
              <option  class="input-group-addon" value="1.35" >Commercial </option>
              <option  class="input-group-addon" value="1.3" > Official </option>
              <option  class="input-group-addon" value="1.25" >Other </option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

    <br>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data- parent="#accordion3" href="#collapseTwo3"> Interior Rendering</a></h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <br>
          <div id="rndr-lobby">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm"><span class="input-group-addon paramtitle">Lobby wall area  </span>
              <input type="number" value=10 min="0" step="0.01" id="rndr-int-wall-area-lobby" class="form-control" onchange="RndrIntPrc();" placeholder=" 0.00     sqm " required="required">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm"><span class="input-group-addon paramtitle">Photo Realistic </span>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">Day</span>
                    <input type="number" value="1" min="0" id="rndr-int-real-day-lobby" class="form-control" placeholder="0 Num" onchange="RndrIntPrc();">
                  </div>
                  <!-- /input-group -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"> Night</span>
                    <input type="number" min="0" id="rndr-int-real-nght-lobby" class="form-control" placeholder="0 Num" onchange="RndrIntPrc();">
                  </div>
                  <!-- /input-group -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm"><span class="input-group-addon paramtitle">Conceptual</span>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">Day</span>
                    <input type="number" min="0" id="rndr-int-conc-day-lobby" class="form-control" placeholder="0 Num" onchange="RndrIntPrc();">
                  </div>
                  <!-- /input-group -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"> Night</span>
                    <input type="number" min="0" id="rndr-int-conc-nght-lobby" class="form-control" placeholder="0 Num" onchange="RndrIntPrc();">
                  </div>
                  <!-- /input-group -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm"><span class="input-group-addon paramtitle">Maket</span>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">Day</span>
                    <input type="number" min="0" id="rndr-int-mak-day-lobby" class="form-control" placeholder="0 Num" onchange="RndrIntPrc();">
                  </div>
                  <!-- /input-group -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" disabled="disabled"> Night</span>
                    <input type="number" min="0" id="rndr-int-mak-nght-lobby" class="form-control" placeholder="0 Num" disabled="disabled">
                  </div>

                  <br>
                  <label class="fa">Interior rendering Total price  </label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="render-int-price" placeholder="0" readonly></input>
</html>

<script>
  document.getElementById("prjstrndr").onchange = function () { RndrIntPrc(); };
  document.getElementById("prjfnrndr").onchange = function () { RndrIntPrc(); };
  document.getElementById("rndr-lobby").onchange = function () { RndrIntPrc(); };
  document.getElementById("rndr-int-wall-area-lobby").onchange = function () { RndrIntPrc(); };
  document.getElementById("rndr-int-real-day-lobby").onchange = function () { RndrIntPrc(); };
  document.getElementById("rndr-int-real-nght-lobby").onchange = function () { RndrIntPrc(); };
  document.getElementById("rndr-int-conc-day-lobby").onchange = function () { RndrIntPrc(); };
  document.getElementById("rndr-int-conc-nght-lobby").onchange = function () { RndrIntPrc(); };
  document.getElementById("rndr-int-mak-day-lobby").onchange = function () { RndrIntPrc(); };

  //interior render cost calculation:

  var
    RIRDL = document.getElementById("rndr-int-real-day-lobby"),
    RIRNL = document.getElementById("rndr-int-real-nght-lobby"),
    RICDL = document.getElementById("rndr-int-conc-day-lobby"),
    RICNL = document.getElementById("rndr-int-conc-nght-lobby"),
    RIMDL = document.getElementById("rndr-int-mak-day-lobby"),

    Totalintrndr = 0;

  document.getElementById('render-int-price').value = Totalintrndr;

  var RndrIntPrc = function () {
    console.log('1');
    var projectStylerndr = document.getElementById('prjstrndr').value,
      projectFunctionrndr = document.getElementById('prjfnrndr').value,
      RIWAL = document.getElementById("rndr-int-wall-area-lobby").value,
      RIRDLNum = RIRDL.value,
      RIRNLNum = RIRNL.value,
      RICDLNum = RICDL.value,
      RICNLNum = RICNL.value,
      RIMDLNum = RIMDL.value,
      XRL = 50000,
      XCL = 25000,
      XML = 10000;

    var intNumD = [];

    [RIRDLNum, RICDLNum, RIMDLNum].forEach(function (n, i) {
      intNumD[i] = (n >= 2 && n < 5) ? n * 0.9 : n == 0 ? 0 : n == 1 ? 1 : n - 1;
    });

    var intNumN = [];

    [RIRNLNum, RICNLNum].forEach(function (n, i) {
      intNumN[i] = (n >= 2 && n < 5) ? n * 0.95 : n == 0 ? 0 : n == 1 ? 1.2 : n == 2 ? 1.9 : n - 1;
    });

    var Totalintrndr = projectStylerndr * projectFunctionrndr *
      (Math.log(RIWAL) * ((XRL) * (intNumD[0] + intNumN[0]) + (XCL) * (intNumD[1]
        + intNumN[1]) + (XML) * intNumD[2]));

    document.getElementById('render-int-price').value =
      (Totalintrndr > 0 && Totalintrndr !== 'NaN') ? Totalintrndr : 0;

  };

  RndrIntPrc();

</script>
```

Comment: can you please highlight the changes that you made?

Comment: Use any compare tool to see it